# How do you modify the spacing of the generated HBox inside the JavaFX ToolBar?

Tags: java, javafx

How do I make changes to generated items using FXML?

When creating a JavaFX ToolBar, a nested HBox (or VBox) is generated automatically.  For example, I would like to set the spacing of this generated HBox to 0.

```
 <ToolBar fx:id="welcomeToolBar" prefHeight="50">
        <items>
                <Button fx:id="closeButton" prefHeight="50" prefWidth="100" onAction="#closeWindow" text="Close" />
                <Button text="New Image" prefHeight="50" prefWidth="100" onAction="#newImage" styleClass="button-accent"/>
                <Pane HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS"/>
                <CheckBox text="Hide this window on application start"
                          fx:id="hideOnLoadCheckBox" onAction="#setVisibilityOnApplicationLoad"/>
        </items>
 </ToolBar>
```

[image: Scenic View snapshot showing automatically generated HBox]

Comment: You might have to implement your own `ToolBar`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the CSS property `-fx-spacing` (uses the [`<size>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typesize) type). You can do this in a separate CSS file and link the file or do this directly in the FXML file using the `style` attribute.

Example FXML:

```xml
<ToolBar fx:id="welcomeToolBar" prefHeight="50" style="-fx-spacing: 0px;">
    <!-- items -->
</ToolBar>
```

Example CSS:

```css
.tool-bar {
    -fx-spacing: 0px;
}
```

The reason this works is that the **default** skin of the `ToolBar` class exposes a `StyleableProperty` for spacing<sup>1</sup>. I found it in the "CSS Analyzer" of *Scene Builder* and the JavaFX 9 (and 8)<sup>2</sup> source code (for some reason can't get *Scenic View* to run). I couldn't find any documentation on this property, however; even in the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).

---

<sup>1. Another undocumented styleable property exposed by the **default** skin (at least in JavaFX 13) is `-fx-alignment` which accepts a `javafx.geometry.Pos`. These properties are applied to the `HBox` or `VBox` depending on if the toolbar's orientation is horizontal or vertical, respectively.</sup>

<sup>2. Still present in the JavaFX 13 source code.</sup>

Comment: Wow this is great! Yeah I definitely didn't see any reference either when I looked at the JavaFX reference. I appreciate you walking this down to such great detail